# Is it possible to have your Outlook agenda show the days your are in the office?

Tags: microsoft-outlook, microsoft-office, scheduling

I work full time, with regular office days from Monday - Friday (that's my workweek, also in Outlook). 2 days a week I'm in the office, the rest of the week I work from home. Using the scheduling assistent in Outlook, people can see if I'm available for a meeting (an empty timeslot) or if I already have meeting planned (a blue block in my agenda, they cannot see the title etc of a meeting). Is it possible to have my agenda show from where I will be working any specific day so people can schedule a face2face meeting in the office on the days I will be in the office, without having to ask me when that is?

Comment: If the issue has been resolved, please mark the helpful replies as answers.

Answer (score 1):

Outlook calendar have an option called “work elsewhere”, you could set your calendar availability status to "Working Elsewhere" on the dates they are working off-campus. This provides insight when scheduling meetings to ensure the proper meeting format is available.

1. Open the Outlook desktop application.
2. Select the Calendar icon from the bottom left corner of the screen.
3. Select New Appointment from the options ribbon at the top of the calendar screen.
4. Enter a Subject (optional) such as "Working Remotely".
5. Enter the Date (select all day) or Date and Time for when you will be working remotely.
6. Select Working Elsewhere from the Show As drop-down in the Outlook Ribbon.
7. Select Save & Close.